# What is the difference between "if x == True" and "if x:"

Tags: python

Hello stackoverflow Community :-)

I am learning Python at the moment and I don't understand the "True/False" concept entirely.

In Python the number 0 is associated to "False" and 1 to "True".

When I write following code

```
x = 2
y = 1

if y == True:
    print("Y is True")
if x == True:
    print("X is True")
else:
    print("X is False")
```

I get "Y is True", because the "1" is truthy. And I get "X is false", but I thought that this should be also "True", because there is a value (x = 2) and not "None, 0, etc.."

When I write

```
if x:
    print("X is True")
else:
    print("X is False")
```

then I get "X is True", because x is not empty and thus truthy.

What is the exact difference between "if x:" and "if x == True"?

Comment: Are you sure you got your indentation right? Python cares a lot about proper indentation!

Comment: Matthias, don't use this code. You have to indent after an if statement!

Comment: I edited your formatting, because it supposedly is not the reason for the behaviour you observe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference is that `if x:` checks the truth value of `x`. The truth value of all integers except 0 is true (in this case, the 2).

`if x == True:`, however, compares `x` to the value of `True`, which is a kind of `1`. Comparing `2 == 1` results in a false value.

To be exact, there are two adjacent concepts:
* the one is the "truth value", which determines the behaviour of `if`, `while` etc.
* the other are the values `True` and `False`, which have the respective truth values "true" and "false", but are not necessary equal ot other true resp. false values.

If you absolutely need to check for the exact values of `True` and `False` for whatever reason, you can do so with `if x is True` or `if x is False`. This ensures that if y is exactly `True` will pass the test, if it is `1`, it won't.

Comment: Can you please add that using `if .. is boolean` is preferable to `if .. == boolean` ?

Answer (score 6):

The `==` operator doesn't compare the truthiness of its operands, it compares their values.

When boolean values are used in a context that requires numbers, such as when comparing them with numbers, they get converted automatically: `True` becomes `1`, `False` becomes `0`.

So

```
if some_boolean == some_number:
```

is effectively equivalent to:

```
if int(some_boolean) == some_number:
```

This is why

```
if True == 2:
```

does not succeed. `int(True)` is `1`, so this is equivalent to

```
if 1 == 2:
```

Answer (score 2):

equivalent ways to look at the problem:

```
"if x" <==> "if bool(x)"
```

since your x is an integer:

```
"if x" <==> "if x != 0"
```

and

```
"if x == True"  <==> "if x == 1"
```