# Are 'True' and 'False' simply objects with a fixed address in memory?

Tags: python, memory

Does each variable which gets assigned a *True* or *False* (e.g: variable = True), reference two constant, unchanging addresses in memory which are reserved for holding respectively True and False?

**In context:**
I was researching the difference between *==* and *is* [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58006256/what-is-the-difference-between-if-x-true-and-if-x#58006312), from which (according to my understanding) i learned that **==** compares the values of two objects, and **is** checks whether or not two objects are one and the same (or rather, whether they occupy the same address in memory).

Then i tried out the following code:

```
foo = False


if foo is False:
    print("1")
```

I was expecting for an error to occur, but it didn't (thinking that 'False' would be treated as a value, and **is** not being able to deal with a value). Instead it passed.

So is my guess correct? Does every boolean variable in fact constantly reference two objects in memory with an unchanging address (True and False)?

Comment: `True` and `False` are _singleton_ objects, if that's what you mean.  There is only one actual occurrence of `True` in a program, and all the mentions of `True` just _refer_ to it.

Comment: I don't know if the memory address is actually fixed or not.

Comment: *EVERYTHING* in Python is an object in memory.  But that doesn't mean that using tests like `foo is False` is a good idea, because that destroys Python's ability to treat *anything* as a boolean value (basically, numeric zeros and empty containers are "falsy", most everything else is "truthy").  The proper way to test for a false value is `if not foo:`.

Comment: @jasonharper If a boolean value is an object in memory, what is the difference between 'if x is True', and 'if x'? Don't they both simply check whether x refers to an address containing the True object? Why is the latter preferred? Is it convention or is there another reason?

Comment: He told you the reason.  `if x is True:` means it will not work with other things that can be used to designate falsity, like 0 or the empty string or list.  Saying `if x:` reads better and is more flexible.

Comment: `1` is a truthy object, but `1 is True` is absolutely not true, because those are two different objects.

Comment: @Tim_Roberts Right. Trying to wrap my head around this.
So 'if x is True' will only pass when referencing True. 'If x' in addition also passes when referencing objects containing truthy values (non-null).
Since the latter encapsulates a wider definition of what is truthy, it is preferred?

Comment: @Magikarp that is `x is True` is true if an only if `x` is *the singleton object `False`*. However, `x` is true for many, many other objects

Comment: @Magikarp Truthy does not mean "non null".

Comment: As an aside, not sure why you expected an error to occur. Conisder, `foo = "foobar"`, then `if x is False` doesn't raise an error (the condition is just not true, and the if block isn't executed). Also, all objects in CPython have a fixed memory address  (this may not be true if certain types of garbage collection were used in CPython, but it is not the case). But if you mean "does `True` and `False` always evaluate to the same object", then that is true. `True` and `False` (and `None`) are all language guaranteed singletons

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The reason i expected it is because i'm new at Python, and this just happened to be a rabbithole i chose to go down in :) Somebody else mentioned the concept of singleton objects (which i am not familiar with), and i might take a gander at it later on. But thanks for the elucidation.

Comment: @Magikarp it just means "there is only one".